# Requiring code line for clicking on button on website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

[image]

I complied the below mentiond code, but I'm not able to figure out how to click on proceed button, the button which I sought to be clicked is marked between arrows in the attached image.

```
Sub TDS_Autofill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

End Sub
```

Comment: You should provide the HTML code from the website to get better answer. To do what you want you will probably need a DOM parser and interact with elements through it

Comment: while inspecting elements this was the line of code which I get from the website for the required Proceed Button : <a href="javascript:sendRequest(281);" class="btn btn-info b-align ">Proceed</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the code of this button it is

```html
<a href="javascript:sendRequest(281);" class="btn btn-info b-align ">Proceed</a>
```

so if you click on the button (which is actually just a link) it actually runs the JavaScript function `sendRequest(281)`. So all you have to do in VBA is to run exactly that function with

```
doc.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"
```

and it would have the same effect as clicking on that button.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub TDS_Autofill()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Dim doc As Object
    Set doc = IE.document
    doc.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"
End Sub
```